# Android AlarmManager not work when app be killed

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I want to write a app to remind people something,
but my alarm not work when user close the app.
I try my to set alarm like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        alarmTime, pendingIntent
    );
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
} else {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

but this is not work
and I try to use WorkManager, but it still not work when app be killed.
I try to download another app, but there alarm work in my phone.

My phone is oppo a75,os version is color os 3.2 ,android version is 7.1.1
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
The solution is that I used a foregrounfd service that works constantly with a constant notification to appear

Comment: It is still work on chinese oem ?